# Omitting a field in biblatex bibliography within a refcontext

Tags: biblatex

Would there be a way to omit a field in biblatex bibliography within a refcontext, to use it such as follows:

```
\usepackage[sorting=nty]{biblatex} 
\DeclareRefcontext{testrc}{sorting=nyt}

\begin{document}

\begin{refcontext}{testrc}
...
\end{refcontext}

\begin{refcontext}[***omit-field***=note]{testrc} 
... [cite references omitting the note field]
\end{refcontext}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit more flexible than just per-refsection - by changing the boolean, you can omit any field at any point. Per-refsection looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sorting=nyt]{biblatex} 
\begin{filecontents}[force]{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{test1,
    AUTHOR         = {R. Author},
    TITLE          = {Title},
    DATE           = {2015},
        NOTE           = {NOTE}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\newbool{nonote}
\AtEveryBibitem{\ifbool{nonote}{\clearfield{note}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{refcontext}
\cite{test1}
\printbibliography
\end{refcontext}

\begin{refcontext}
\booltrue{nonote}
\cite{test1}
\printbibliography
\end{refcontext}

\end{document}
```

[image]